# How to execute two quires in JDBC

Tags: android, oracle

I am fresh to android, and i tried to connect JDBC to my application and its working properly. it displays database content in listview format. and now I want to display the number of counts, for that i want to execute two queries at the same time, is there any possibility to do this. please let me know how to execute two quires in JDBC

Comment: two queries at the same time? or do you want to use the result of one query as the input for the next one? if thats the case, use subqueries

Comment: Two queries at the same time..!! is this possible in JDBC..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time, if you need more than one thing from the database, you can combine them into one query.

For example, if you want a list of employees, as well as a total count of employees, you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT emp.name,
       emp.salary,
       COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_count
FROM   employees emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

two queries at the same time? or do you want to use the result of one query as the input for the next one? if thats the case, use subqueries